# Current Y Scroll Position: Always returning Zero

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm attempting to get the current Y scroll position that the end user is at when viewing a web page that has no iframes and I am using the following code:

```js
var currentPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
```

This code works as expected on Android and PC devices as far as I can see.
However, on a physical iPhone 8 device using Safari, the value returned is always zero.

I had tested the iPhone 8 using Chrome Device Toolbar and it works as expected, so this could be an issue directly related to Safari.

Has anyone had this issue before, and if so, how did you overcome it?